# How to display object's keys and values in react component

Tags: reactjs

I have `ControlSection` component that one of it's props is `statistics` object prop. I want to display with `<h2>` all the key and values of the object. How can I do it?

ControlSection:

```
const ControlSection = ({ statistics }) => {
    return (
        <div className='gameStatistics'>
            {
                Object.keys(statistics).forEach(key => 
                    <h2>key: statistics[key]</h2>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Statistics example:

```
const statistics = {
    Score: score,
    Level: level,
    Best: bestScore,
};
```

Comment: You can use object entries: `Object.entries(statistics).map(([key,value])=><div>key:{key},value:{value}</div>)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`forEach` returns `undefined`. Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which returns the JSX for each item in a new array.

JSX also requires the `{ }` braces to evaluate text as JS.

Since you're creating a series of `<h2>` elements, React needs a `key` property to be set on the elements. Using `key`s from the object is sufficient since they're guaranteed to be unique strings. However, you might consider using a list (`<ul>` or `<ol>` parent element with `<li>` children) as an alternative to the header elements.

Also, you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to access both the key and value for each pair in an object in a slightly more intuitive way than `statistics[key]`:

```
const ControlSection = ({ statistics }) => {
    return (
        <div className='gameStatistics'>
            {
                Object.entries(statistics).map(([key, val]) => 
                    <h2 key={key}>{key}: {val}</h2>
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```